# Request Body of POST method in Fiddler2

Tags: wcf

The method call is successful without Request body. When I use below Request body, I get HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request. Do you see any obvious problem with below requst body?

Request Body

```
{ 
    "_userConfigData":{"UserName":"bXZpbmphbXVyaQ==", "FirstName":"User1", "LastName":"Last1", "ContactInfo":"None" }, 
    "_configResult": "Miscellaneous"
}
```

Request Headers

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:1706
Content-Length: 167
```

Here is the server side method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UpdateUserDetails/?_clientIP={_clientIP}&AdminName={AdminName}", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)] 
public void UpdateUserDetails(UserConfigData _userConfigData, ConfigResult _configResult, string _clientIP, string AdminName)
{
    // 
}
```

Here is the URL that I use with Fiddler2:

http://localhost:1706/WCF/UserConfig/UserConfigService.svc/UpdateUserDetails?_clientIP=localhost&AdminName=admin

Thanks,

Comment: Hmm the json data and the POST header looks fine to me.  Try debugging the server code if possible to find out why it is returning 400?

Comment: See the update above. When Request Body is present in Fiddler2 the control doesn't come to this method. However, if NO Request Body, the control does come to this method.

Comment: What is the URL you are giving to Fiddler?

Comment: Try aggregating UserConfigData and ConfigResult into a parent object, and have UpdateUserDetails() accept that object instead?  Your json should remain unchanged if you did that btw.  I'm not sure if this would work but it seems like an object format matching issue.

Comment: I changed the method as follows, there is some improvement. The call comes to the method but userConfig is null. Do you know if same JSON works for this method signature also?
public void UpdateUserDetails(UserConfigObject userConfig, string _clientIP, string AdminName)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get your code to work, but I had to make some modifications.

1. I had to move the data carried by the query string into the body itself, otherwise it didn't work.
2. I had to get rid of the BodyStyle Wraped option.

Anyway, here is the updated model objects with your data:

```
public class UserConfigData
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ContactInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public UserConfigData UserConfigData { get; set; }
    public string ConfigResult { get; set; }
    public string ClientIp { get; set; }
    public string AdminName { get; set; }
}
```

The server side method:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UpdateUserDetails", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void UpdateUserDetails(Result result)
{
    //
}
```

The json that you pass in:

```
{
    "AdminName":"String content",
    "ClientIp":"String content",
    "ConfigResult":"String content",
    "UserConfigData":{
        "ContactInfo":"String content",
        "FirstName":"String content",
        "LastName":"String content",
        "UserName":"String content"
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Fiddler request screen shot:
[image: Fiddler request screen shot]

And the request gets to the server UpdateUserDetails() Handler:
[image: UpdateUserDetails]

Comment: I am still seeing the same issue even with these changes. Can you please provide me the JSON that you are using in the Fiddler2 Request Body.

Comment: I already pasted them above in my answer.  I tried it and it works fine for me.  Let me post some screen shots

Answer (score 7):

I changed my service like the posting above and it did not work until I noticed the first screen shot provided. In the fiddler header is the line

Content-Type: application/json

This allowed me to send data to the service. After changing the return type to string I was able to get raw data back.